# Sequelize: user.checkPassword is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a prototype function inside sequelize model, to validade my password:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    'User',
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
      password_hash: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {
      hooks: {
        beforeSave: async user => {
          if (user.password) {
            user.password_hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  );

  **User.prototype.checkPassword = function(password) {
    debugger
    return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password_hash);
  };**

  return User;
};
```

but when I export this model to my controller and try do call user.checkpassword, it gaves me **TypeError: user.checkPassword is not a function**:

```
const { User } = require('../models');

class SessionController {
  async store(req, res) {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = User.findOne({ where: { email } });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'User not found' });
    }

    **if (!(await user.checkPassword(password))) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Incorret password' });
    }**

    return res.status(200).send();
  }
}

module.exports = new SessionController();
```

what can it be??

my sequelize version is "sequelize": "^5.21.5"

Comment: Have you tried using the newer [ES6 Class Definition](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html) approach?

Comment: I'm gonna have a look at it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
User.findOne({ where: { email } });
```

returns a promise. You probably meant to do

```js
const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });
```

instead of

```js
const user = User.findOne({ where: { email } });
```